# Scanln in Golang doesn't accept whitespace

Tags: string, go, io, stdin

How can I use `Scanln` that accepts whitespace as input?

Comment: It already does. It accepts all whitespace except for a new line. Maybe if you give us an example of the input you want to scan, and a small program showing how you are scanning it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can't use the [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package's `Scanln()` and similar functions for what you want to do, because quoting from `fmt` package doc:

> Input processed by verbs is implicitly space-delimited: the implementation of every verb except %c starts by **discarding leading spaces** from the remaining input, and the %s verb (and %v reading into a string) **stops consuming input at the first space** or newline character.

The `fmt` package intentionally filters out whitespaces, this is how it is implemented.

Instead use [`bufio.Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner) to read lines that might contain white spaces which you don't want to filter out. To read / scan from the standard input, create a new `bufio.Scanner` using the [`bufio.NewScanner()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#NewScanner) function, passing `os.Stdin`.

Example:

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
if scanner.Scan() {
    line := scanner.Text()
    fmt.Printf("Input was: %q\n", line)
}
```

Now if you enter 3 spaces and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the output will be:

```
Input was: "   "
```

A more complete example that keeps reading lines until you terminate the app or enter `"quit"`, and also checks if there was an error:

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
for scanner.Scan() {
    line := scanner.Text()
    fmt.Printf("Input was: %q\n", line)
    if line == "quit" {
        fmt.Println("Quitting...")
        break
    }
}
if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error encountered:", err)
}
```

Comment: Amazing, I haven't completely read all of the documentation regarding fmt package, thanks @icza

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Anyway it's confusing for me that a command which obviously shortens from "Scan line()" doesnt reads till the line ends.